# In Welcome to Night Vale, what name(s) were given to Khoshek's kittens?

Tags: names, welcome-to-night-vale

In *Welcome to Night Vale*, Khoshekh, the cat hovering in the men's bathroom at the radio station, has a litter of kittens.  They were all adopted (but continue hovering in the bathroom and are just visited by their adopters). I recall that at least one adopter named his kitten after himself, but I don't remember what the name was, or if any of the other kittens had names mentioned in the show.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from [scanning the podcast transcripts](http://sitecomber.com/search.php?domains=www.sitecomber.com&client=pub-1307489338039489&forid=1&ie=ISO-8859-1&oe=ISO-8859-1&cof=GALT%3A%23008000%3BGL%3A1%3BDIV%3A%23FFFFFF%3BVLC%3A663399%3BAH%3Acenter%3BBGC%3AFFFFFF%3BLBGC%3A150567%3BALC%3A000000%3BLC%3A000000%3BT%3A0000FF%3BGFNT%3A0000FF%3BGIMP%3A0000FF%3BLH%3A0%3BLW%3A0%3BL%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fsitecomber.com%2Flogo-490x90.jpg%3BS%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitecomber.com%3BFORID%3A11&hl=en&channel=5823071447&q=kittens&sitesearch=http%3A%2F%2Fcecilspeaks.tumblr.com%2F&sa=Search&safe=active), the only kitten that has been canonically named is "**Larry Leroy**", mentioned in episode 55; "[The University of What It Is](http://cecilspeaks.tumblr.com/post/99042573486/episode-55-the-university-of-what-it-is)"

> His kittens are, of course, also floating in fixed locations in the
>   same bathroom, and are being cared for by their various owners. Larry
>   Leroy, out on the edge of town, has especially taken after one of the
>   kittens, who he has named – confusingly – “Larry Leroy.”

Answer (score 2):

According to the [transcript](https://nightvale.fandom.com/wiki/Transcript:LOST:_CAT) of episode 207, "LOST: CAT," the cats' adoptive names were Mixtape, Larry Leroy, and Potato, whilst their birth names were Rafael, Jeremiah, and Anissa, respectively.

> Anyway, **I showed her the other 3 cats: Mixtape, who I named, he’s my favorite; Larry Leroy, who Larry Leroy named; and Potato, who looks and acts like a potato.**
>
> Tonya tried her darnedest to talk to them, but still got nothing about Khoshekh’s whereabouts. **All Tonya was really able to tell me was that these aren’t the cats’ real names. Tonya said Potato’s real name is Anissa [rhymes with Clarissa], and that Larry Leroy’s real name is Jeremiah, and Mixtape’s real name is Rafael, though he likes Mixtape better than his birth name.**